# Javascript - How do I call the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see I've created three objects, each one has a different array.

```
var redmeat = {options: ["beef", "steak", "kangaroo"]},
    whitemeat = {options: ["chicken", "turkey"]},
    fish = {options: ["salmon", "tuna"]};
```

Then, in the HTML I've created a select field, with three corresponding options.

```
<select name="meat-type">
    <option value="redmeat">Red meat</option>
    <option value="whitemeat">White meat</option>
    <option value="fish">Fish</option>
</select>
```

Now, whenever the user selects the field, I want to be able to display the correct array in my console. (For instance, when red meat is selected, the console will log "beef", "steak", "kangaroo".)

```
$('select[name=meat-type]').change(function(){
    var e = $("select[name=meat-type] option:selected").val();
    function updatefield (e){
        console.log(e); //this works, easy.
        f = e.options; //but this doesn't work, return as undefined
        console.log(f);
    };          
    updatefield(e);
});
```

So the question is; how do I call the object?

Comment: the phrase "call the object" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: The 'e' you got is just a string, not the object you defined.

Comment: Yes 'e' is just a string, but the question is; is there a way I can turn that string into an object, so then I would be able to do e.options?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to modify your object and put them into single object.

After that you can easily call the object key and get it's value.

```
var meatObj = {
  redmeat: ["beef", "steak", "kangaroo"],
  whitemeat: ["chicken", "turkey"],
  fish: ["salmon", "tuna"]
};

$('select[name=meat-type]').change(function(){
  console.log(meatObj[this.value]);
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6EMh/) for above code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring those variables, build an object:

```
var meats = {
  redmeat: {options: ["beef", "steak", "kangaroo"]},
  whitemeat: {options: ["chicken", "turkey"]},
  fish: {options: ["salmon", "tuna"]}
};
```

Then:

```
    f = meats[e].options;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to add more meat types in future. Hence I want to be able to keep redmeat, whitemeat and fish all as separate objects. I also want to be able to add more keys and properties to each object.

Comment: They are separated objects. To add another, say other, you would later just write something like: `meats.other = { options: ["tofu"] }`

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response I was sick, thank you for all your answers but the kind of answer that I was looking for was the eval method.

So all I gotta do is...

```
    f = eval(e); //and then...
    g = f.options;
```

done!